# Welchen Dialekt spreche ich?

Tags: dialect

Ich komme aus der Gegend Stralsund,  Vorpommern und bin ein bisschen verwirrt. Ich spreche schon zum größten Teil hochdeutsch aber so ne sachen wie

> ik, meen, dit/dat

oder

> wie geiht di dat

schleichen sich dann doch immer mal ein. (Was ich auf jeden Fall mag, da ich finde, dass pures Hochdeutsch doch etwas kulturlos und langweilig klingt) Jetzt frag ich mich aber, ist das mecklenburgisch oder der "ausgestreckte" Arm aus Brandenburg/Berlin?

Meine Oma kann Plattdeutsch und generell reden viele ältere Menschen hier platt (zumindest in den ländlichen Gebieten in der gegend). Ich würde behaupten es ist mecklenburgisch angehaucht von Berlinerisch, aber was meint ihr?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontinentalwestgermanisches_Dialektkontinuum

Answer (score 4):

[Missingsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missingsch). Überwiegend Hochdeutsch mit niederdeutschen Überbleibseln, in Deinem Fall - vorpommerschen. Dir kommt es etwas Berlinerisch vor, weil es auch eine Mischvarietät darstellt. 
Suche mal nach sonstigen Eigenschaften [des Vorpommerschen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecklenburgisch-Vorpommersch) bzw. solcher Mischvarietäten (bspw. *Lang mich mal die Kanne Milch*), ich bin gespannt auf Deine Selbstbeobachtungen.

Comment: Der Artikel beschreibt das Phänomen, mit der noch interessanten Zusammenfassung: "Wir haben also ein doppeltes Vordringen: Das Hochdeutsche gegenüber der Berlin-Brandenburgischen Umgangssprache, und diese gegenüber dem Niederdeutschen." https://www.moz.de/artikel-ansicht/dg/0/1/980964/

Answer (score 1):

Ich als Berliner würde

> wie geiht di dat

als eindeutig platt einstufen (wobei ich nicht weiß, ob sich Ostsee-Platt von Nordsee-Platt signifikant unterscheidet).
"meen" klingt natürlich schon auch berlinerisch, "dit" beinahe (wäre eher "det", aber der Unterschied ist akustisch nicht sehr stark).
"Ich" wird in Berlin zu "ick(e)", mit kurzem i und scharfem "ck". Falls Dein "ik" darauf hindeutet, dass das "i" eher lang ist, wäre das jedenfalls nicht berlinerisch.